# C# BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have two files. One which contains a variable of type DataProgressBar and calls the startAsyncWorker() method before loading its own components. The other is the DataProgressBar displayed below. When I run my program and call startAsyncWorker() in the other files the behavior

**EXPECTED:** small window with a progressbar is displayed, loading from 0 to 100 as the work in WorkerDatabaseInsertion is performed. Then when finished my first class file which contains the DataProgressBar, will move on to its next instruction.

**EXPERIENCED:** small window with a progressbar is displayed, no change is made to the UI, thread seems to freeze as no output or evidence of processing is shown. I close the window, the calling file resumes.

```
public partial class DataProgressBar : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bgw;
        private String _path;
        private LFPReader _lfp;
        private Access db;


            public DataProgressBar(String p, LFPReader reader, Access database)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                /* Set private class level variables */
                _path = p;
                _lfp = reader;
                db = database;
                db.open();
                /* Set up worker and progressbar */
                bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                SetUpWorker(bgw);
                progressbar.Maximum = 100;
                progressbar.Minimum = 0;
                progressbar.Value = 0;
            }

            public void startAsyncWorker()
            {
                if(bgw.IsBusy != true)
                {
                    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This methods exists for completeness, but we will
            /// probably not need to directly cancel the worker from here.
            /// --Kurtpr
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            public void cancelAsyncWorker(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
                {
                    bgw.CancelAsync();
                }
            }

            private void SetUpWorker(BackgroundWorker worker)
            {
                worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; // we need this in order to update the UI
                worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // Not sure why, but we may need this to cancel

                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(WorkerDatabaseInsertion);
                worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(WorkerProgressChanged);
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerBurnNotice);
            }

            private void WorkerDatabaseInsertion(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                ImageInfo ImageData = new ImageDB.ImageInfo();
                double size = _lfp.GetImageData().ToArray().Length;
                int index = 0;
                //_path is setup in loadAsLFP() before this call.
                foreach (var image in _lfp.GetImageData())
                {
                    index++;
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    image.FullPath = Path.Combine(_path, image.FullPath);
                    ImageData.Add(new ImageDB(image));
                    db.insertImage(new ImageDB(image));
                    worker.ReportProgress((int)(index/size));
                }
            }

            private void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }

            private void WorkerBurnNotice(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                db.close();
            }
        }
```

I suspect I am wrong about a fundamental aspect of BackgroundWorker. Where is my logical fault here?

**EDIT** Here is the code that calls and creates the DataProgressBar object.

```
private void createDb(string filePath, LFPReader lfp)
        {
            //Set up LFP related objects.
            ImageData = new ImageDB.ImageInfo();

            //create database file.
            filePath = filePath.Replace(".lfp", ".mdb").Replace(".LFP", ".mdb");
            _lfpName = filePath; // update to use the database file
            Access db = new Access(filePath.Replace(".lfp", ".mdb"));
            db.createDatabase();

            //used for calculating progress of creating this new database.
            var progressbar = new DataProgressBar(_path, lfp, db);
            progressbar.ShowDialog();
            progressbar.startAsyncWorker();

            CurImage = ImageData.First().FullPath;
            //Make sure that data context is set for these images.
            DataContext = ImageData;

        }
```

Comment: I think `worker.ReportProgress((int)(index/size));` should be `worker.ReportProgress((int)(index * 100/size));`

Comment: Most likely your progress calculation is off. If index goes from 0 to size you'll only get zeroes until the end. Though that wouldn't freeze anything. And what is a "calling file"? You mean a different class? What is the definition of that?

Comment: can you try `worker.ReportProgress((double)(index/size));` I had a similar experience once.
And even if this doesn't work, put a breakpoint and follow through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your progress calculation logic is faulty here.

`worker.ReportProgress((int)(index/size));`

**This line will always report progress as 0.** So, your progress bar will be always stuck at 0 position.

Instead, use following to report progress in percentage.

`worker.ReportProgress((int)(index*100/size));`

**Update:**
The code you have shared seems to be correct.
I think the problem lies in the way you have implemented progress bar.

I suppose you are calling startAsyncWorker method from main thread as follows;

```
var dpb = new DataProgressBar(p, reader, database);
dpb.startAsyncWorker();
```

After above two lines are called, **your main thread should be free.**

That means, following code will cause your progressbar to freeze for 50 seconds because, even if your DoWork is running perfectly, UI will not be updated since main thread is not free.

```
var dpb = new DataProgressBar(p, reader, database);
dpb.startAsyncWorker();
Thread.Sleep(50000);               //Main thread is busy for 50 seconds
```

**Update 2:**

The real problem lies in following lines;

```
var progressbar = new DataProgressBar(_path, lfp, db);
progressbar.ShowDialog();
progressbar.startAsyncWorker();
```

Actually `ShowDialog()` method shows `DataProgressBar` as Modal dialog. That means, the control will not go to next line unless you close that dialog.

Your problem should be solved using following code;

```
var progressbar = new DataProgressBar(_path, lfp, db);
progressbar.startAsyncWorker();
progressbar.ShowDialog();
```

It will first start your background worker and then DataProgressBar dialog will be shown.

Comment: Thank you for that correction, but after testing that out the progressbar still does not respond. As I mentioned, I believe this is an issue with the BackgroundWorker as the method attached to worker.DoWork seems to never be called.

Comment: That is exactly how I am calling it in the main thread. Would the course of action then be to move the background worker methods and object into the main thread before using?

Comment: You don't have to move any code from BackgroundWorker. Just make sure that nothing is being executed on Main thread after calling `dpb.startAsyncWorker();`. If you are having any problems doing that, you should share code where `startAsyncWorker()` is being called.

Comment: The main thread is another UI. Would that cause problems? After this executes it doesn't do anything else because this process has to be done before it can display anything.

Comment: @KurtPrice, Please post code for method from where `startAsyncWorker()` is called as well as object of `DataProgressBar` is created.

Comment: That is exactly the solution to my problem. Thank you so much for the help. It would have taken me ages to realize that subtle mistake.